# How to fetch a listitem in the ViewModel from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In a C# MVC project, I have a ViewModel that contains a string List (CodeBlock_Data) and a selectionlist (CodeBlock_Names). They have corresponding IDs.
The selectlist is presented as a dropdownbox, the CodeBlock_Data is not linked to a html object.

When I select an item from the combobox, I want to access the corresponding value in the CodeBlock_Data list.
I do not want to submit the form.

What I have so far;

```
function Insert_Block_Code() {
    var CodeBlock_Selection = document.getElementById('CodeBlock_Selection');
    alert(CodeBlock_Selection.selectedIndex); //This displays the correct index
    alert(@Model.CodeBlock_Selection); //This always displays 0
    text = "@Model.CodeBlock_Data[Model.CodeBlock_Selection]"; //Always returns the data from the item with ID 0
    Update_PageCode_Text(text);
}
```

The only solution I see with my current knowledge is to introduce a hidden list object for the CodeBlock_Data, so I can access that from the JavaScript code. But that feels wonky.

Perhaps I am approaching the issue the wrong way? So here's my intention;
I want a combobox that contains a number of short descriptive names.
Once the user presses an insert button, another, related, block of text will be inserted in a textblock. The names and code is stored in a database table.

Comment: Unclear what you're saying, but to _start_ based only on the comments in your posted code, realize that it "always displays...." is _expected_ because your razor code `@Model...` is evaluated **once**, on page load - it's server side, not client side. It doesn't "re-run" things based on events in the browser/client-side. You'll have to handle _client side events_ in Javascript and do XHR/Ajax if you need server side resources (or reload/submit, etc.).

Comment: I never realised @Model was evaluated serverside.... but of course it is.
Thanks!
I'll rethink the solution.